# Upper and lower bounds from gstat::krige() and gstat::idw()

Tags: r, interpolation, kriging, inverse-distance-weighted, gstat

Is it possible to obtain lower and upper bound values from a kriging estimation using `gstat::krige()` in the same way it can be obtained from a simple `lm()` model?

The following `lm()` example comes from http://pebesma.staff.ifgi.de/modellierung/course.pdf (end of page 22, 23)

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
data(meuse)
names(meuse)
data(meuse.grid)
names(meuse.grid)

#Now try:
coordinates(meuse) = c("x", "y")
coordinates(meuse.grid) = c("x", "y")
gridded(meuse.grid) = TRUE

# We can use the prediction errors provided 
# by lm to calculate regression prediction intervals:
plot(log(zinc) ~ sqrt(dist), meuse)
x = 0:100/100
lzn.lm = lm(log(zinc) ~ sqrt(dist), meuse)
pr = predict(lzn.lm, data.frame(dist = x), interval = "prediction")
abline(lzn.lm)
lines(sqrt(x), pr[, 2], lty = "dashed", col = "red")
lines(sqrt(x), pr[, 3], lty = "dashed", col = "red")
pr = predict(lzn.lm, data.frame(dist = x), interval = "confidence")
lines(sqrt(x), pr[, 2], lty = "dashed", col = "blue")
lines(sqrt(x), pr[, 3], lty = "dashed", col = "blue")
title("95% confidence intervals (blue) and prediction intervals (red)")

#Next, we can make maps of the 95% prediction intervals:
pr = predict(lzn.lm, as.data.frame(meuse.grid), interval = "prediction")
meuse.grid$fit = pr[, 1]
meuse.grid$upper = pr[, 3]
meuse.grid$lower = pr[, 2]
spplot(meuse.grid, c("fit", "lower", "upper"), sp.layout = meuse.grid, layout = c(3, 1))
```

I want to obtain these fit/lwr/upr values inside my kriging output object, next to 'var1.pred' (i.e., kriging_output$lwr). Is it possible? And can the same be done using `gstat::idw()`?

I tried `kriging_output = predict(gstat_model, new_data, interval = "prediction")` but it only returns 'var1.pred', not fit/lwr/upr.

Not sure if it's relevant but my gstat_model involves four predictors (DA ~ temp+Temp.Seasonality+um.rel+CWD)